# Plotly barcharts with POSIXct and daylight-savings-time

Tags: r, plotly, dst, r-plotly

I want to plot a barchart timeseries with timestamps on the x-axis. My problem is the **daylight-saving in Octobre**, as there are 2 timestamps at 02:00, one with **CEST** timezone and one with **CET**.

The plotly-barchart superimposes these values, which is hard to spot and looks like an error when you hover over the barchart as you will find that the value does not correspond to the y-axis.

How can I display **these 2 bars side by side**, without changing the `tickmode` to "array" and defining `tickvals/ticktext`?

```
library(plotly)

df <- structure(list(value = round(runif(46, 20, 26), 3), 
                     timestamp = structure(c(1603576800, 1603584000, 1603587600, 1603591200, 1603594800, 1603598400, 
                                             1603602000, 1603605600, 1603609200, 1603612800, 1603616400, 1603620000,
                                             1603623600, 1603627200, 1603630800, 1603634400, 1603638000, 1603641600,
                                             1603645200, 1603648800, 1603652400, 1603656000, 1603659600, 1603576800,
                                             1603584000, 1603587600, 1603591200, 1603594800, 1603598400, 1603602000, 
                                             1603605600, 1603609200, 1603612800, 1603616400, 1603620000, 1603623600,
                                             1603627200, 1603630800, 1603634400, 1603638000, 1603641600, 1603645200,
                                             1603648800, 1603652400, 1603656000, 1603659600), 
                                           class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "Europe/Berlin"), 
                     col = c(rep("#FFBA00", 23), rep("#B9CC2E", 23)), 
                     name = c(rep("Grp1", 23), rep("Grp2", 23))), 
                row.names = 1:46, class = "data.frame")

plot_ly(data = df, text = "text") %>%
  add_trace(x = ~timestamp, y = ~value, type = "bar",
            marker = list(color = ~col),
            text = ~sprintf("Time: %s<br>Value: %s", timestamp, value),
            hoverinfo = "text",
            name = ~name) %>% 
  plotly::layout(xaxis = list(title = 'Time', type = "date"),
                 barmode = 'group')
```

Comment: Why do you exclude the use of `tickvals/ticktext`? I'd use UTC `tickvals` and CET/CEST `ticktext`.

Comment: Because I would like to keep the dynamic tick creation of plotly, as plots can potentially also have 1000's of individual bars.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think you'll have other choices currently. [Here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/171#issuecomment-178583549) is a pretty old GitHub issue - closed but doesn't seem to be solved. If you do find something else please let me know.

Comment: A related statement: `Changes our internal date linearization to use UTC rather than local milliseconds. Every day on a Plotly graph will now be 24 hours long, with no daylight shifts.`  from [here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/pull/1194#issue-95087563)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wraping up my comments to an answer for future readers:

`plotly` currently doesn't support displaying daylight saving time natively:

> Changes our internal date linearization to use UTC rather than local
> milliseconds. Every day on a Plotly graph will now be 24 hours long,
> with no daylight shifts.

source: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/pull/1194#issue-95087563

Accordingly, the only possibility I'm aware of, to work around this issue is using the `tickvals` and `ticktext` arguments in plotly's `layout` function (not desired by @SeGa and this is reasonable as we'll have duplicated tick labels. Nevertheless, maybe the following helps others).

```
library(plotly)

DF <- structure(list(value = round(runif(46, 20, 26), 3), 
                     timestamp = structure(c(1603576800, 1603584000, 1603587600, 1603591200, 1603594800, 1603598400, 
                                             1603602000, 1603605600, 1603609200, 1603612800, 1603616400, 1603620000,
                                             1603623600, 1603627200, 1603630800, 1603634400, 1603638000, 1603641600,
                                             1603645200, 1603648800, 1603652400, 1603656000, 1603659600, 1603576800,
                                             1603584000, 1603587600, 1603591200, 1603594800, 1603598400, 1603602000, 
                                             1603605600, 1603609200, 1603612800, 1603616400, 1603620000, 1603623600,
                                             1603627200, 1603630800, 1603634400, 1603638000, 1603641600, 1603645200,
                                             1603648800, 1603652400, 1603656000, 1603659600), 
                                           class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "Europe/Berlin"), 
                     col = c(rep("#FFBA00", 23), rep("#B9CC2E", 23)), 
                     name = c(rep("Grp1", 23), rep("Grp2", 23))), 
                row.names = 1:46, class = "data.frame")

# DF$timestamp_utc <- DF$timestamp
# attr(DF$timestamp_utc, "tzone") <- "UTC" 

plot_ly(data = DF, text = "text") %>%
  add_trace(x = ~as.numeric(timestamp), y = ~value, type = "bar",
            marker = list(color = ~col),
            text = ~sprintf("Time: %s<br>Value: %s", timestamp, value),
            hoverinfo = "text",
            name = ~name) %>% 
  plotly::layout(xaxis = list(title = 'Time',
                              ticktext = ~timestamp, 
                              tickvals = ~as.numeric(timestamp),
                              tickmode = "array"),
                 barmode = 'group')
```

[image: result]

---

**Minor edit:** If we want to reduce the amount of ticklabels without a lot of effort we can use `pretty` in `ticktext` and `tickvals`:

```
ticktext = ~pretty(timestamp), 
tickvals = ~as.numeric(pretty(timestamp))
```

[image: pretty]

Related docs: [Formatting Ticks in R](https://plotly.com/r/tick-formatting/)